# how to use Authorize Attribute in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize-attribute

I need your help, please I am not aware about how to use the authorize attribute in asp.net MVC.

For example

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /workflow/home/
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return RedirectToAction("signIn", "Accounts");
    }


    public ActionResult TrackingPage()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult profile()
    {
        ViewBag.profile = true;
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult content()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

All the methods are protected else the index method, my question is how to authorize a user who submitted his user name and password in the sign in form correctly, what is the code that I have to write to make this user authorized.

I am new to asp.net MVC and not accustomed to use the attributes, I used to use the session to validate the users.

I do not know if authorize attribute works with the forms or just works with the users created from the computer management i.e(windows authentication).

Please I am a little confused and need your help.

Comment: Why don't you learn from beginner's tutorials, such as http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

Comment: The code you are looking for is in the AccountController that is in the default MVC project that visual studio creates for you. Specificially the Login and Logout methods.